# Convert several separate lists to integers and get sum

Tags: python, regex, list, integer

I need to take elements produced by a list, convert them to integers, then get their sum. I would like to do this using a basic for loop to convert the lists to integers, but can't figure out how to write the code to convert the lists into integers. The data that comes out of my code so far looks like this:

```
['9085', '5174']
['7297']
['9488']
['8370', '1014', '4870']
['4719']
['3004', '4969', '2458']
['9445', '7420']
['50', '1690', '8374']
```

... and so on. My code looks like this thus far:

```
import re
hand = open('Regex-Actual.txt')
numbers = []
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    y= re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    if len(y) > 0 :
        print y
numbers = [int(y) for y in numbers]
print numbers
```

I am a beginner at Python, so explanations with answers mean a lot!

Comment: Is the data Python arrays/lists? Or is it literal strings that need to be parsed?

Comment: several separate strings that need to be parsed. I am guessing converted into integers first, then added together for the sum.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use regex for this problem, you can make numbers from strings of numbers easily!

```
string_list = ['8370', '1014', '4870']
number_list = [int(x) for x in string_list]  # using list comprehension
sum(number_list)
# 14254
```

If you are reading it in from a file, you might get the lists in the string form of a list. E.g you will get `"['8370', '1014', '4870']"`. To make a list from this:

```
import ast
lst = "['8370', '1014', '4870']"
lst = ast.literal_eval(lst)
#lst becomes ['8370', '1014', '4870']
```

Comment: Hi @PeterWang. The list I have is pretty extensive, and the output is several separate lists of strings. I need to convert those several separate lists into integers to add them together. For some reason, the list comprehension doesn't work, it could be the way I am typing it in:
import re
hand = open('Regex-Actual.txt')
for line in hand:
 line = line.rstrip()
 y = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
 if len(y) > 0 :
  print y
numbers = [int(x) for x in y]
sum (numbers)